# Query all posts in a certain category

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to show all post in a page of a certain category. Here's what I did so far:

```
<?php
$args = array(
             'category_name' => 'diy-tutorial',
             'post_type' => 'post',
             'posts_per_page' => 3
             //'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
             );
query_posts($args);
$x = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

It's actually working but it wouldn't let me navigate for the next pages of the categories Like for example, i have 30 posts in that certain category, so my code will show me three posts per page right? The next>> link won't show up as well as if I change the number of posts to show per page, it won't work as well...

If you have an alternative way of showing it please let me know.

Comment: Are you talking about pagination? The display of page numbers commonly at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I am a little rusty on my wordpress, but the way I like to get posts is by passing a querystring to get_posts

```
$catID=get_cat_id('diy-tutorial');
$queryString="cat=".$catID."&numberposts=1000";
 global $post;
 //execute the query from the string 
 $myposts = get_posts($queryString);
//loop thru and do stuff
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 setup_postdata($post);
the_post();
endforeach;
```

see the codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Its best practice to build up an argument array if you can :)

Comment: You are correct, as a general rule, but personally for me I find the "get request style" query string form easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the buttons and possibly build up the function: Read the Codex friend: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Function_Reference

Also, I believe the commented out part of your code must be active to declare paged.

```
<nav class="wp-prev-next">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="prev-link"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', "bonestheme")) ?></li>
        <li class="next-link"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;', "bonestheme")) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have added that already but I'm using a wordpress plugin to have it look better..... I can see the div where it has been put but nothing shows up...

Comment: What do you mean by you can see it? In dev console, or an empty div area meant for it on the page?